# 2 Mootools AJAX function at the same time?

Tags: php, ajax, mootools

I'm new to Javascript and Mootools and I was wondering if someone can help me learn by solving a problem that I currently have.

index.php has a form, which submit to it self and initiate this code

```
if($_POST['subbutton']=='Run')
{
$data=$object->do_compare();

}
```

I would like to know, how can I do a mootool ajax function, that will send the post['run]'
to a  php script file ( data.call.php )  where the object reside and have it run.

however, I don't want any respond from data.class.php, as that object writes it's results to a txt file (data.txt)

the 2nd part,
 would be an ajax function (that also run at the same time as the first ajax function) and reads a php file, every 5 seconds and bring the data back to index.php

so the squence of operations will be

index.php

form get clicked and start 2 ajax functions.

the first one, only submit the POST['run'] to a php script.

the second function, will go to another php file and get a respond from it every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test the below, so use at your own risk.  But that's pretty much the gist of it.

```
_form.addEvent('submit', function(event) {

    // your first call
    new Request.JSON({
        url: "your-first-rpc",
        data: {
            subbutton: "Run"
        },
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            // handle response here.
        }
    }).post();

    // your second call which runs every 5 secs.
    (function() {
        new Request.JSON({
            url: "your-second-rpc",
            data: {
                subbutton: "Run"
            },
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                // handle response here.
            }
        }).post();
    }).periodical(5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.addEvent('domready', function() {

            $('dbform').addEvent('submit', function(e)
            {


                new Event(e).stop();

                var intervalId =setInterval(function(){

                    var Ajax2 = new Request(
                        {
                            url: '/tools/getdata.php',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: 'read=true',
                            onComplete: function(response)
                            {
                                $('21').set('text', response);
                            }

                        }

                ).send();},1000);





                var postString = 'subbutton=' + $('subbutton').value;

                var Ajax = new Request({
                    url: '/tools/getdata.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: postString,
                    onRequest: function()
                    {
                        $('message').set('text', 'loading...');

                    },
                    onComplete: function(response)
                    {

                        $('message').set('text','completed');
                         clearInterval(intervalId);

                    },
                    onFailure: function() {

                        $('message').set('text', 'ajax failed');
                    }
                }).send();
            });
        });
    </script>
```